# Upper bounding a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, upper-lower-bounds

Let $\epsilon \in (0, 1)$. Consider the following sequence with $a_0 = \sqrt{2\epsilon}$.

$$a_n = a_{n-1} + \sqrt{2(a_{n-1} + \epsilon)}$$

I would like to bound this sequence as $a_n \leq f(n, \epsilon)$. Writing down the first few terms, we have
\begin{align}
a_0 &= \sqrt{2\epsilon}\\
a_1 &= \sqrt{2\epsilon} + \sqrt{2(\sqrt{2\epsilon} + \epsilon)}\\
a_3 &= \sqrt{2\epsilon}+\sqrt{2(\sqrt{2\epsilon}+\epsilon)}+\sqrt{2(\epsilon+\sqrt{2\epsilon}+\sqrt{2(\sqrt{2\epsilon}+\epsilon)})}
\end{align}

My guess is that it should look like $a_n \leq c(n)\epsilon^{1/2^n}$ or something similar to this. Any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: did you try setting $b_n = a_n + \epsilon$?

Comment: @Alex, thank you for the comment. This substitution would give me $a_n \leq b_{n-1} + \sqrt{2b_{n-1}}$. But I would like a bound purely as a function of $n$ and $\epsilon$ and I don't see yet how to go from a function of $b_n$ to that. Or did I misunderstand your comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Alex suggests it is convenient to consider $b_n = a_n+\epsilon$ since you have that
$$b_{n+1} - b_n = \sqrt{2 b_n}\,.$$

You have that $b_0 = \epsilon + \sqrt{2\epsilon}$.

Now consider $u(t)$ the solution of the Cauchy problem
$$\dot u(t) = \sqrt{2 u(t)}\,;$$
$$u(0) = \epsilon + \sqrt{2\epsilon}\,.$$

You have
$$u(t) = \frac{1}{2}\left(t + \sqrt{2}\sqrt{\epsilon+\sqrt{2\epsilon}}\right)^2\,.$$

Now you can show that $a_n\leq u(n)-\epsilon$ for all $n$.

Indeed you have that for each $n$ there exists a $x\in(n,n+1)$ such that
$\dot u(x) = u(n+1) - u(n)$. Since $u$ has positive second derivative, $\dot u(x)>\dot u(n)$. By definition of $u$ you have
$$u(n+1) - u(n) \geq \dot u(n) = \sqrt{2u(n)}\,.$$

Since $u(0) = b_0$ you have
$$u(1) = u(0) + (u(1)-u(0)) \geq u(0) + \sqrt{2u(0)} = b_0+\sqrt{2b_0} = b_1\,.$$
By induction you show that if $u(n)\geq b_n$ then
$$u(n+1) = u(n) + (u(n+1)-u(n))\geq u(n) + \sqrt{2u(n)}\geq b_n+\sqrt{2b_n} = b_{n+1}\,.$$

So for all integer $n$ you have $u(n)-\epsilon\geq b_n-\epsilon = a_n$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just to check, are $\alpha_n, \beta_n$ the same as $a_n, b_n$?

Comment: Oh yep sorry.. I'll edit it

Comment: Thank you! One last question - how did you find $u(t)$ i.e. the solution of Cauchy problem? I can verify that it is indeed correct but was wondering if there was a systematic way to obtain it.

Comment: For $u' = \alpha u^n$ you get $u'/u^{n} = \alpha$ and then you integrate both sides. $\int_{t_0}^t u'(s)/u^n(s)ds = \alpha (t-t_0)$. So $\int_{u(t_0)}^u(t) dv/v^n = \alpha (t-t_0)$ and by inverting you find the solution.